# Split a String in Hadoop, but only got the first index of array

Tags: java, hadoop, split, reduce

I got a wired problem of split method in Hadoop. It's very simple code like this:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (Text each : values) {
            String[] array = each.toString().split(",");
            context.write(key, new Text(array[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

The values are String like this: "A,0,0,1". What I want to do is to try to split this String and put them into an array. If I execute the code above, It will show ArrayOutOfIndexException. But I can access the array of index 0, which will return an "A". I tried to figure it out, then I changed the "array[1]" part to "Integer.toString(array.length)". Turns out it returns 1. I'm so confused. I'm pretty sure the input data is correct, no null value, no more spaces.

When I changed my code to this:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (Text each : values) {
            for (String eachPart: each.toString().split(",")){
                context.write(key, new Text(eachPart));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can return every value of input, the result will like this(say the key is "0,0"):

```
0,0    A
0,0    0
0,0    0
0,0    1
```

But again when I tried to put this to an array like this:

```
public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (Text each : values) {
            int i = 0;
            String[] tmp = new String[4];
            for (String eachPart: each.toString().split(",")){
                tmp[i] = eachPart;
                i++;
                context.write(key, new Text(tmp[1]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can not get the array, it will be NullPointerException. If I changed the "tmp[1]" to "tmp[0]", it will be fine, it returns an "A". I'm so confused. Any one got an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to expect to receive an `Iterable<Text>` that has single text of "A,0,0,1" in it. Yet, from your description, you actually got `Iterable<Text>` that contains four texts, first one is "A", second one is "0", etc.

Comment: But it should be one Text, if I don't split it and just output it, it will return "A,0,0,1".

Comment: It's dangerous to assume that every record contains exactly 3 commas. You should be asserting that before doing anything else.

Comment: Actually, I did assert that before, I just deducted any other code to simplify the problem and try to figure out what's wrong there.